# find the min of an array Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array with some numeric values and an array with some strings. Just like these arrays:

```
t_nextevent = ["wake", "wake", "tired", "wake"]
t_nexttime = [8, 16, 7, 11]
```

I want to find the minimum of the array `t_nexttime` if the `t_nextevent` is equal to `wake`. For this, I have written this code.

```
t_next_event = 1000.0
t_index = 0
for i in range(num_i):
    if (t_nextevent[i] != "tired" and t_nexttime[i] < t_next_event):
        t_next_event = t_nextevent[i]
        t_index = i
```

However, I get this error.

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'str'
```

Can anybody help me to find a solution to this?
Bests,

Comment: what is your expected answer?

Comment: Thank you @SreeramTP for your comment. Either find a way to solve the error or a way to find the minimum value by considering also ```t_nextevent```

Comment: `t_nexttime[t_nextevent == "wake"].min()`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to get the lowest value in the array. You can do it like this:

```
t_index = t_nextevent.sort()[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use numpy, you can have:

```
import numpy as np 
i = np.argmin(np.array(t_nextevent))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could zip your arrays together, filter out the `wake` values and then return the minimum:

```
min([time for event, time in zip(t_nextevent, t_nexttime) if event == "wake"])
```

> 8

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
min_val = min([int(t_nexttime[i]) for i in range(len(t_nexttime)) if t_nextevent[i] == 'wake'])
print(min_val)
```

It returns the minimum value in the list of those values in `t_nexttime`, whose corresponding value in `t_nextevent` is `wake`.

This prints

> 8